# Naming convention for form-related files and folders

Tags: php, forms, symfony

This is the folder structure of my project:

[image]

Is the Form folder o.k.? I divided it into three major subfolders:

1. Entity - contains getters and setters for each form field, just like it's done in the docs. Its object is used as `createFormBuilder()`'s argument
2. Type - class responsible for creating all form fields
3. Handler - class handling form proccessing backend

---

I've also heard about Model subfolder...what would it do?

---

I couldn't find anything about dividing Form folder into separate responsibilities in the symfony2 tutorial, so thanks for any answers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder structure is okay but if you want to follow the [Symfony Coding Standards](http://symfony.com/doc/master/contributing/code/standards.html) your form-handlers and form-classes must use studly-caps names like SomeForm and FooFormType.

It's a good practice to suffix your classes by with Type, Handler, ...

PSR-1 states:

- Class names MUST be declared in StudlyCaps.

Symfony follows the standards defined in the [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md), [PSR-1](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md) and [PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) documents.

Comment: "It's a good practice to suffix your classes by with Type, Handler, ...", - Could you please provide more information on why this is good practice?